# TypeError on modal function

Tags: jquery

I used jstree in my program. I can create and store it in database. But, while retrieving it from DB in another page, I am getting jstree is not a function error, and 1st time I can open dialog box of that page. After clicking some other dropdown , I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function" this error. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is saying `$(...).modal`  is not a function. Are you using Jquery-UI or any library to provide that modal functionality? Check that first.

Comment: It seems that your plugin is not loaded or its parent.You can check it in the network tab (or similar) of your browser console (F12).